# Graphql file upload automation using karate

Tags: automation, graphql, karate

I'm new to GraphQL ,and I'm trying to automate a feature which
uploads an xlsx file. For automation I'm using Karate, my Karate
feature file steps are given below:

```
    * header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
    * header x-Token = token
    * multipart file file = { read: '/Spend/data.xlsx', filename: 'data.xlsx', contentType:
'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
}
    * multipart field map = {file : ["variables.input.file"]}

    * def query = read('queries/createImportJob.graphql')
    * def operation = 'CreateImportJob'
    *  def variables = {"input":{"category": 'SPEND' }}
    * request { query: '#(query)' , variables: '#(variables)', operation: '#(operation)'}
    * url url
    * method post
    * print response
    * status 200      

    Right now I'm getting the response as 500. Please suggest me the correct way to pass the multipart data into grapghql request.
```

Comment: please also do a search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=upload+%5Bkarate%5D

Comment: @PeterThomas , there is no information on passing the multipart file into variables field (using karate ), could you plz point me to any related documentation. I'm stuck here.

Comment: file-upload problems are impossible for anyone to solve remotely unless you provide a WORKING cURL command (as given in the link). so read it